# How do I handle duplicate keys in HashMaps in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap. I wrote a method for reading files and printing them, but I just thought that HashMap does not tolerate duplicate keys in the file, so I need to do something about it, e.g. saving the same key but with some kind of a character in the end (like just _ or something like that so they differ from each other). I can't come up with the solution (maybe I could catch an exception of just write an if-block). Could you please help me?

```
public static HashMap<String, String> hashmapReader(File test3) {
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>(); 
    try (BufferedReader hmReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(test3))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = hmReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] columns = line.split("\t");
            String key = columns[0];
            String value = columns[1];
            data.put(key, value); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong"); 
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: What behavior do you need when you have a key collision?

Comment: From your statement and code, it's not clear what your objective is. Why would you split a line on tab characters and either you expect it to only have one tab character and split into 2 parts or you are trying to capture all split tokens on the line. What is your key supposed to be? It must be unique and should represent a unique identifier that allows your to search for the key later in the Map. If that's not what your intent is, then you may be using the wrong datastructure.

Comment: Before your `put` line: `while (data.containsKey(key)) key += "_";`.

Comment: @pczeus I have a file with two columns, like "Tokyo Japan \n Berlin Germany ... etc." and I need to save these as a key-value structure, so HashMap comes in handy. I just thought what if the key "Tokyo" comes multiple times instead of one, what do I do in this case?

Comment: I can't say for certain that I could come up with an answer for this...you're probably not wrong in that you *could* want a key-value structure, but until you run into an actual problem, I'm not sold that any answer you get here would be complete because your own requirements are incomplete.

Comment: @ta4le I guess my point is, don't you want to store all separate values for each occurance of Tokyo or Berlin? A Hashmap is fine, but I wold have stored a List as the value in the Map with the city as the key, something like Tokyo={value 1, value 2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you actually ask for:

Before your `put` line:

```
while (data.containsKey(key)) key += "_";
data.put(key, value);
```

This will keep on checking the map to see if `key` already exists, and if it does, it adds the `_` to the end, and tries again.

You can do these two lines in one:

```
while (data.putIfAbsent(key, value) != null) key += "_";
```

This does basically the same, but it just avoids having to look up twice in the case that the key isn't found (and thus the value should be inserted).

---

However, consider whether this is actually the best thing to do: how will you then look up things by "key", if you've essentially made up the keys while reading them.

You can keep multiple values per key by using a value type which stores multiple values, e.g. `List<String>`.

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>(); 
// ...
data.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Yes, I actually wrote the code initially with `HashMap<String, List<String>>` structure, but the task was to write it with <String, String> structure

Comment: The only problem with this example is if there are 3 values for the same key - you would wipe out the arraylist each time if the key already exists and only set the last value found in the ArrayList

Comment: @pczeus no, because `computeIfAbsent` only adds a new ArrayList if there isn't one already.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a control on the key if it already exist in the HashMap `data`.
In order to do this you can use `get(key)` method of the [HashMap Java Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) which returns *null* if the **key doesn't exist**:

```
if(data.get(key) != null)
         key = key + "_";
data.put(key, value); //adding the split line array to the ArrayList
```

If it already exists (didn't return *null*) then you can change his name by adding a character at the end, e.g. `"_"` as you said.

**EDIT**: The answer above mine pointed out to me a fact: "What if there are more than 2 identical keys?".
For this reason, I recommend following his solution instead of mine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it out